# Missing log4j file in cassandra conf folder

Tags: configuration, cassandra

I am going through the course from 
http://academy.datastax.com/courses/installing-and-configuring-cassandra
There is a log4j file used in that video. Which, I could not find it the app downloaded from http://www.planetcassandra.org/cassandra/ dsc-cassandra-2.1.7-bin.tar.gz is there any other place I can find this?

Thanks in Advance
Venkat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The course uses Cassandra 2.0.9, you've downloaded 2.1.7.

Between 2.0 and 2.1, Cassandra switched its logging framework from Log4J to [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/). The equivalent file in 2.1 would be `conf/logback.xml`. The concepts are very similar (logging category, levels...) but the syntax is a bit different.

I'm not sure if the course has you change anything in that file or just mentions it for reference, but for full details about the syntax I suggest the Logback documentation.